# Understanding async dispatch actions using redux thunk

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-redux, redux-thunk

I was just going though the files that dispatches ACTIONS in a reactjs app and basically came across the following function::-

```
// When app inits
export const init = () => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: TYPES.SET_LOADING });
  await dispatch(getConfig());
  await dispatch(getGenres());
  dispatch({ type: TYPES.REMOVE_LOADING });
};
```

I am a bit confused as to what the async is doing ahead of the dispatch , i am used to seeing normal vanilla javascript async functions like so:

```
anasyncfunc = async () => { 
   // write you're code here
}
```

But the above code confuses me a little. Can somebody please explain this to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function which uses the `await` keyword must me marked with async which you have pointed out in your example

```
anasyncfunc = async () => { 
   // write you're code here
}
```

In this function we can now use `await` since it was marked with `async`.

In the case of the thunk, we are effectively creating an outer function called `init` which when called will return an anonymous function. This anonymous function will accept `dispatch` as an argument and will make use of the `await` keyword, and as such needs to be marked with the `async` keyword.

In short, we really are just creating a function which will want to use `await` and therefor must be marked with `async`.

I hope this clarifies it.